# Objective-sharpie ApiDefinition contains overloaded methods?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie, xamarin.ios-binding

After some head scratching I finally got objective-sharpie to bind a `.framework` file successfully, however the `ApiDefinition.cs` file that it generates contains some irregularities.

```
    // @optional -(void)flyerView:(WFKFlyerView * _Nonnull)flyerView gotSingleTap:(id<WFKFlyerViewTapAnnotation> _Nullable)annotation atPoint:(CGPoint)point;
    [Export("flyerView:gotSingleTap:atPoint:")]
    void FlyerView(WFKFlyerView flyerView, [NullAllowed] WFKFlyerViewTapAnnotation annotation, CGPoint point);

    // @optional -(void)flyerView:(WFKFlyerView * _Nonnull)flyerView gotDoubleTap:(id<WFKFlyerViewTapAnnotation> _Nullable)annotation atPoint:(CGPoint)point;
    [Export("flyerView:gotDoubleTap:atPoint:")]
    void FlyerView(WFKFlyerView flyerView, [NullAllowed] WFKFlyerViewTapAnnotation annotation, CGPoint point);

    // @optional -(void)flyerView:(WFKFlyerView * _Nonnull)flyerView gotLongPress:(id<WFKFlyerViewTapAnnotation> _Nullable)annotation atPoint:(CGPoint)point;
    [Export("flyerView:gotLongPress:atPoint:")]
    void FlyerView(WFKFlyerView flyerView, [NullAllowed] WFKFlyerViewTapAnnotation annotation, CGPoint point);
```

So this actually won't compile because Visual Studio aptly points out that the methods have the exact same definition despite having different `[Export]` attributes. I tried changing it so there is only a single method with multiple `[Export]` attributes but that isn't allowed either. Not sure what to do here.

Also there is a `using` statement at the top that I think is trying to point to my `Native Reference` that I have setup in the Xamarin project in Visual Studio for Mac but it doesn't work (`type or namespace could not be found are you missing an assembly reference, etc.`)

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Fixed up warnings by commenting out duplicate implementations in generated code i.e. those that have the same parameters etc.
2. Removed empty generated interfaces.
3. Commented out “using xxx(your SDK name)” in ApiDefinition.cs — not 100% sure why this was necessary!

Comment: So I actually ended up renaming the methods to match their export name: `FlyerViewGotSingleTap, FlyerViewGotDoubleTap, FlyerViewGotLongPress` instead of removing 2/3. I also just commented out the using statement like you mentioned - thank you! I didn't realize it was an unnecessary using statement I thought it was important.